# How can we draw a symbol like normally open/closed contacts in the tikz or latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits, tikz-circuit-lib

I am facing lots of difficulty in drawing a symbol called normally open/closed conatct in tikz and latex. so I need help with drawing such a symbol and different versions of it as attached in the snip.[image: normally open contacts]

Comment: What you have tried? Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that shows what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you. It would also be good to know w=in what contexts you need to use this. Constructing these symbols out of square brackets would not be hard, so do you need `tikz`? Some context would be helpful. Does the circuitikz package already do what you want?

Comment: There s no such a symbol (first time /me see; can be easily confused with a capacitor) in circuitikz, but it's quite easy to reproduce in plain TikZ... Please post what you have tried!